# Liquid or powder that passes through an orifice at a consistent rate

Tags: fluid-dynamics, time, flow, density

This I a really odd and specific question, and I'm not sure this is even where to ask.
A few weeks ago I thought about making a clock based on water flowing from an orifice.  The obvious issue is that the flow rate would vary significantly based on environmental conditions around the clock.
Does anyone know of a liquid or maybe a powder that will flow more consistently from a container into another across normal temperature and pressure shifts?

The obvious first guess would be sand like in an hour glass, but I was hoping someone knew of a better solution because the flow rate of sand is finicky in other more unpredictable ways.

I should add that the supply container will always be topped off with more media so that the mass (pressure) of liquid or powder is not changing with time.

Comment: How about using a gas? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choked_flow Might be easier though to measure the weight of a closed, pressurized container from which the gas is flowing than it would be to measure the gas itself after it has escaped. That would, of course, be somewhat incompatible with your desire that "the supply container will always be topped off..."

Comment: P.S., Your question may be closed on the grounds that it has more to do with engineering than it has to do with physics.